# Update Point ID as Start Node and End Node to Line through FME

Tags: fme-form, line

I need your help to perform the below process in FME.

I have two layers: Pole Data (Point) and Cable (Line).

Cable has no ID.

I want to keep the Cable which is going through the Pole.
Then make the cable as Single segment between two poles.
Then I want to update the Start ID and End ID (Pole ID) to each segment (Cable layer).

Please share the design of workbench and what parameters I will use in each transformer.

Comment: Have a look at the PointOnLineOverlayer transformer.  Also the SpatialRelator.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that your points are on line, and cables are linestrings

Lines->Linejoiner (by cable type? and using only end point) (creates longest possible lines) -> PointOnLineOverlay
Points -> PointOnLineOverlay (this cuts all lines at points.)

Then Lines from PointOverLay -> CoordinateExtractor (use 0 index for start points and -1 to last endpoint) -> Create points, and use SpatialRelator or FeatureMerger to merge start and endpoint with points